# How to render random objects from a table in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to render random objects from table in React Native.
I use React Native EasyGrid for my table.
I try to build a memory game in React Native.
I need this code for shuffle cards.

This is the code that I make for test all functions.
They want me to give more informations, but I don't have more.

The code:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Button, Text, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, ActivityIndicator,} from 'react-native'
import { Col, Row, Grid } from "react-native-easy-grid";


export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
  color: "red",
  card: "this.refs.card",
  cards: "[...card]"
  }
  }
 

 
 
_code to randomized (Like shuffle(array) in JS, but not this function !) {

// I need the code here

}


componentDidMount() {
 
  this.setState({cards: this._shuffle(this.state.cards)});

}



  _test = () => {

 this.setState({color: this.state.color === "red" ? "blue" : "red"});

 }
 
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

 <Grid ref="deck">  
  <Col>
   <Row>
   
   <TouchableOpacity ref="card" onPress={this._test}>
    <Text style={{ height: 15 }}>1</Text> 
   </TouchableOpacity>
   
   </Row>
   <Row>
   
   <TouchableOpacity ref="card" onPress={this._test}>
    <Text style={{ height: 15 }}>2</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
   
   </Row>
   <Row>
   
   <TouchableOpacity ref="card" onPress={this._test}>
    <Text style={{ height: 15 }}>3</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
   
   </Row>
   <Row>
   
   <TouchableOpacity ref="card" onPress={this._test}>
    <Text style={{ height: 15 }}>4</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
      
   </Row>  
  </Col> 
 </Grid>   
   
   <View><Text style={{color: this.state.color}}>XXX</Text></View>
   
</View>      
    
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Can somebody help me please ?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to shuffle a JavaScript array (and how to build a grid of components based on that array). Beginners often fail to break down their problems into parts. Shuffling an array is very basic, and unrelated to React.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Comment: Ok, so how can I Randomized object from an array in React Native ?

The code from "How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?", doesn't work in react Native. Have you a code to do that in React Native ?